# Can I safely take down this wall?

Tags: structural

I am contemplating removing the wall highlighted in green on the blue prints of my house - I do not believe the separation it brings is necessary.
If I understand my blueprints correctly, it is not load-bearing and can be removed safely.
Am I reading the structural plan properly and is it safe to do so?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pay a structural engineer - safer for 1/2 hour of professional advice.

Comment: If the house is in a earthquake zone, then @SolarMike  has a good suggestion.  It probably is not load bearing, but it might be preforming another important function that we are not familiar with.